# How can I overwrite CSS?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm using Drupal 8 and I have to customize an existing theme.

Should I just make changes in specific files in docroot/themes/theme_name or do I have to create subdirectory somewhere in docroot/sites and there put the files that I wanted to change? I mean make there files with CSS styling that I want to change.

With this theme I cannot create subthemes in Drupal.

Comment: I guess here is the answer: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/creating-a-sub-theme and here: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/folder-structure

Comment: "Libraries can now be overridden and extended by themes" https://www.drupal.org/node/2497313